# Resource File for C# is not Responding correctly in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, c#-2.0

I have an application in C#. This application is in 2 language french and English.

Whenever there is a change in Field.Text, i just use to change the value in the Resource file. Everything worked fine after that.

Today I am facing a difficulty in doing this.

Initailly for the Resource.Name `GENERAL_UI_FACTEUR_GRAVITE` value was `Criteria of non-resectability`

Now i have changed the value of `GENERAL_UI_FACTEUR_GRAVITE` to `Reason for non-resectability`

[image]

When i run the application , in the UI it displays old value only.

So i debuged the code, in the debug also i find the old value only.

[image]

I tried finding the old value using CTRL F ,

[image]

Can anyone tell me the reason for it?

Comment: try clearing cache.. and rebuild solution after cleaning

Comment: how can i miss this... Thanks for reminding.

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: @coder771 Yes .. thanks

Comment: i have added my comment as answer. Can you accept as answer and upvote as it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clearing cache.. and rebuild solution after cleaning

Answer (score 1):

1. You are searching in Form1.cs file, try to do it with Resources.en.Designer.cs file.
2. Resource-files are compilable. Try to rebuild your app and ensure that Resource file was saved before.